# how to export multiple rdlc report to excel oneclicked

Tags: c#, winforms, export-to-excel, rdlc

I have Multiple Rdlc reports, I want to export these reports via a one clicked event into a single Excel Sheet. How can I achieve this?

Please see below code, that converts only one rdlc report to excel

```
private void ExportReport(string exportTo)
    {
        if (objMaster.Current == null || objMaster.Current.Id == 0) return;
        long id = objMaster.Current.Id;

        frmInvoiceReport frm = new frmInvoiceReport();
        // frm.HasSplitByDept = chkSplitByDept.Checked;
        frm.HasSplitByField = ddlSplitBy.Text;
        frm.ObjInvoice = objMaster.Current;

        frm.ExportFileType = exportTo;
        var list = General.GetQueryable<vu_Invoice>(a => a.Id == id).OrderBy(c => c.PickupDate).ToList();
        int count = list.Count;

        frm.DataSource = list;

        frm.GenerateReport();

        frm.ExportReport(objMaster.Current.InvoiceNo, exportTo);
    }
```

Comment: Export them in separate files. Then merge those file in a single excel file.

Comment: Let me know if you are still interested in getting an answer. I posted an answer for you previously but it seems you don't know how to send a feedback on answers or maybe you are not interested in the question anymore.